# Is it possible to mount a logical volume without wiping the data?

Tags: linux, filesystems, redhat, mount

This command wipes the data under `/opt/myfolder`

`mount /work/volumegroup/logicalvolume /opt/myfolder`.

Is there a way to mount it while keeping all the date under `/opt/myfolder`?

Comment: Are you trying to _overlay_ the data from the logical volume with the data that already exists in `/opt/myfolder`?

Comment: The data isn't wiped, it's just hidden because the mount point now refers to the contents of the volume. When you unmount, you'll be able to see it again.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I would like to use the extra disk space with /work/volumegroup/logicalvolume for the file system /opt/myfolder. Shall I report my question at unix & linux forum then?